# Trying build a user input dice rolling program in Python, but I can't get my input to go into my def

Tags: python, dice

This is the code so far. I'm new to Python and programming so this is a bit of a frankencode.
I want the user to input the size die they would like to roll and how many they want to roll. I'm getting nothing to come out once I've coded this.

```
import random

die_size = int(input('What is the size of your die? [enter a #]'))
rolls = int(input('How many would you like to roll? [enter a #]'))

def dice_sim(die_size, rolls):

results = 0
dice_sum = 0

    for i in range(0,rolls):
        results = random.randint(1,die_size)
        print("Die %d rolled %d." % (i+1,results))
        dice_sum += results

    print("Total of %d dice rolls is: %d" % (rolls,dice_sum))

    return None
```

Comment: the code doesn't even compile as it is

Comment: Is this indented the same way as your code is? Because at least one line after `def` should be indented, or the function has no body. Also, are you actually *calling* `dice_sim` at any point?

Comment: As it is, it looks like the indentation is off for the line `results = 0` and `dice_sum = 0`. These should be indented four spaces each to capture them in the `def dice_sim`

Answer (score 1):

Besides some syntax errors, you need to call your function passing the desired input as arguments and return the result of your calculations.

After fixing your syntax and calling the function as desired, your code should look somehow like this:

```
import random

# fixed errors (indentation and function name)
def dice_sum(die_size, rolls):
    results = 0
    dice_sum = 0    
    for i in range(0, rolls):
        results = random.randint(1, die_size)
        print("Die %d rolled %d." % (i+1, results))
        dice_sum += results
    print("Total of %d dice rolls is: %d" % (rolls, dice_sum))
    # return the result of your calculation instead of `None`
    return dice_sum

# get user input (you might think about catching errors)
die_size = int(input('What is the size of your die? [enter a #]'))
rolls = int(input('How many would you like to roll? [enter a #]'))

# pass input values to function and print result
result = dice_sum(die_size=die_size, rolls=rolls)
print(result)
```